# Add-on menu is empty after install

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I have an issue with my **published** add-on. I have noticed that after installing it from GSuite Marketplace submenu in the "Add-ons" tab is empty (it contains only "Help" btn).

Only reopen of the document fixes the issue.

Here are my onInstall and onOpen triggers:

```js
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem("Home", "showSidebar")
    .addItem("Search Selected Term", "openWithSelected")
    .addItem("Settings", "openWithSettings")
    .addToUi();
}
```

I have tried solutions and advices from similar issues but none of it manage to resolve the problem. Also, I have caught error that says: “Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context at onOpen(index:14) at onInstall(index:6)”.

My OAuth scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Comment: This seems to be a bug, see [here][1]. [1]:https://issuetracker.google.com/141500083